# Disable custom taxonomy on admin bar

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy

I created a custom taxonomy and i want to disable the taxonomy to show on the admin bar below my custom post type. How do i disable it?.

The reason i want to disable is because the user is not allowed to add a category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you have a look in the Codex? The option your are searching for is '`public`'

Just add it as an argument in your call to `register_taxonomy()` like this:

```
  $args = array(
    'public'        => false,
    ... [your-other-arguments] ...
  );

  register_taxonomy( 'genre', array( 'book' ), $args );
```

Docs go here:

> **public**
>
> (boolean) (optional) Should this taxonomy be exposed in the admin UI.
>
> Default: true

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Comment: Thank you! it worked. I should have read the codex before asking. was stupid of me :P